# Get the Type behind the Interface of the return value

Tags: c#, interface

Given this little example code:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testInstance = new TestClass();
        Func<TestClass, IComparable> testFunction = (test => test.DoubleProperty);
        var functionType = testFunction.GetType();                       // "Func`2"
        var returnType = testFunction.Method.ReturnType;                 // IComparable
        var typeOfReturnType = testFunction.Method.ReturnType.GetType(); // RuntimeType
    }
}

class TestClass
{
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }

    public double DoubleProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get the Type behind `IComparable` which should be in this case `double`.

That `testFunction.GetType();` will return *Func´2* is clear to me. 
The return `IComparable` of `testFunction.Method.ReturnType;` is also clear and has the value I would expect. 
But is it possible to get the original return type `double` without Invoking the Method `testFunction`?

Comment: Unless you want to interpret the IL to find the return type, then no, it's not possible (that applies to all methods, actually - it's not specific to `Func`). An option would be to use `Expression<Func<TestClass, IComparable>>` instead - in which case, you could easily get the value.

Comment: Consider also what you would want to happen if the function was declared as so: `(test => GetRandomNumber() > 10 ? (double)5 : (int)5)`. Clearly in this case you could *only* get the type by actually running the method.

Comment: @Rob The way with `Expression<T>` sounds very good. I also have expected this answer.

Comment: A very tricky way is invoking the delegate using a safe value and get the return type. But as @RB. said, the implementation of the delegate is probably not that simple, it sometimes cheats you.

Comment: @JensHorstmann How would it work though? The method could return multiple different types depending on runtime information, such as the current time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing my comment, I realized it's a bit more complicated than interpreting the `IL`, and that it's not *definitely* doable in all cases.

Consider the function:

```
Func<TestClass, IComparable> testFunction = test => {
    if (rand.Next(0,2) == 1)
        return new Implementation1();
    else 
        return new Implementation2();
}
```

There's no way ahead of time to determine which implementation is going to be returned.

However - this *also* applies to using `Expression` instead.

The short answer is: 'No', unless your method is fairly well-known at compile time (that is, you know that it will only return one concrete type). Even then, it's a bit tricky.

In your case, it's possible if we know, for example, that the expression is simply a `MemberExpression` (and in this case, cast to `IComparable`).

Assuming you defined your expression as follows:

```
Expression<Func<TestClass, IComparable>> testFunction = (test => test.DoubleProperty);
```

You could then get the return type with this:

```
((testFunction.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MemberExpression).Type
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was searching for. i will check if i can apply this to all my cases.